# It is reasonable to read data on disk parallelly?

Tags: parallel-processing, filesystems, system

In an application, one may need to read the data/files on disk and load them into memory. Many programming languages have support to use multiple CPUs to do the work. I am wondering whether it is a reasonable option to read the disk parallelly. The parallel/concurrent routines will harm the disk, right?
Could you please provide some advice on how to design this kind of system? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after performance, then reading data in parallel is the best thing you can do. The more requests you can provide a disk the faster it can complete the aggregate set of operations.

The only problem with reading data concurrently is that you need to be able to handle it correctly in your application. Typically this means using threads, although you can find OS specific solution that may help with this, such as AIO on linux.

Lastly, the term reasonable is somewhat loaded. While it may be faster to read data concurrently, is there a good use case/does it improve the user experience/is it worth the extra code complexity? In most cases, the answer to that would be no.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind answer and comments! I'm not familiar with hard disk and operating system (OS). From your first comment, it seems there are some good designs in OS, or the file system to be created for the parallel reading onto the disk. If the files are separately saved on the different region of the disk, how does the file system predict the random reading operations? In most circumstances, the reading operations are random. Maybe we can organize the small files to a large file, then the data will be saved in physically near blocks on the disk, facilitating the reading.

Comment: @mining With SSDs your goal is to maximize parallel reads/writes (Queue Depth) and typically maximum IO bandwidth isn't possible until you have completely filled the device's IO queue. In some cases batching small I/O can be helpful as you do still want to perform I/O at the device block size. With spinning disks, the same optimization mostly applies except that seeks are expensive, so, to maximize performance you would want to perform sequential I/O. The easiest way to do this is to design your application around performing I/O with a large chunk/block size ( >=16MB ).

Comment: *If you are after performance, then reading data in parallel is the best thing you can do.* Well, not necessarily.  With spinning disks equipped with only one set of r/w heads and using general purpose operating systems, attempting to read multiple files 'in parallel' can generate a lot of contention for access to the r/w heads (and other elements of the i/o channel) and slow down overall transfer rates.  The situation is probably even worse if multiple processes/threads want access to different parts of the same file.  I would test the validity of this answer.

Comment: Hi, @HighPerformanceMark, thanks a lot for your kind comment. Yeah, I'm wondering whether there are any good solutions to read the different part of the same file parallelly.  Maybe the LMDB or HDF5 file format may have some good designs for efficient file content organization, facilitating the block reading (I'm not sure).